# how to remove previus scatter in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

in my code i wants to draw movings points on a 3d graph with the animation function but when it draw the new point it dont erase the previus point my code look like this

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]

#ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

def draw_graph(i):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]+=1
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')


anima = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(),draw_graph,interval=1000)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `ax.clear()` before the `ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')` line.